# ilk target directory

Tags: visual-c++, incremental-linking

If incremental linking is enabled, Visual C++ generates the *.ilk file in $(TargetDir), can I override this behavior and redirect it to another directory? (without using a post-build step)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual C++ 6.0 and Visual C++ 2008 is not possible to select a different dir for the ilk file. Valid options for incremental linking are `/INCREMENTAL:YES` and `/INCREMENTAL:NO`.

Also, if you create a post build step to move the ilk file to a different location, Visual C++ will not be aware of this, so is the same as dissabling incremental linking at all, since Visual C++ will not find the ilk file.

HTH.

Comment: One can create a pre-build step to restore the file moved in the post-build step, though.

Comment: As of *Visual Studio 2013*, you still cannot change the location of where the `*.ilk` file is stored.